# free complex with mod-p coefficients

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, gt.geometric-topology

How does one prove the following fact. I could not find anything in literature.

Let $\pi$ be a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_p$ and let $W$ be a free $\pi$-complex. Then for any space $X$ there is the isomorphism of homology groups in $\mathbb{F}_p$-coefficients

$H_*(W \otimes_{\pi} C_{\ast}(X)^{\otimes p}) \cong H_{\ast}(W \otimes_{\pi} H_{\ast}(X)^{\otimes p})$.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $C_\ast$ is a chain complex of vector spaces over any field and $H_\ast$ is its homology, then, viewing $H_\ast$ as a chain complex, there is a chain map $r:C_\ast\to H_\ast$ inducing the obvious isomorphism in homology and there is a chain map $i:H_\ast\to C_\ast$ inducing its inverse. This results in an equivariant splitting $H_\ast^{\otimes n}\to C_\ast^{\otimes n}\to H_\ast^{\otimes n}$. The other factor contributes nothing to the homology of $W\otimes_{\pi}-$, because its homology is trivial and $W$ is free.

To see that the resulting isomorphism between $H_\ast(W\otimes_{\pi} C_\ast^{\otimes p})$ and $H_\ast(W\otimes_{\pi} H_\ast^{\otimes p})$ is independent of the chosen splitting $(r,i)$, first note that it depends only on $i$ and that its inverse (therefore also it) depends only on $r$. Now if $(r',i')$ is another such splitting then the splitting $(r',i)$ yields the same isomorphism as $(r,i)$ and also the same isomorphism as $(r',i')$.

By similar reasoning the isomorphism is natural (with respect to chain maps).

Note that the field did not have to be $\mathbb F_p$, and $p$ did not have to be prime, and the chain complex did not have to come from a space.

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the fact that $(C_\ast(X),\partial)$ and $(H_\ast(X),0)$ are weakly equivalent chain complexes when coefficients are taken in a field (which is surpressed from the notation). The reason for this is that the exact sequence
$$ 0 \to \mathrm{Im}\partial \to \ker\partial \to H_\ast(X)\to 0$$ always splits at the level of vector spaces.

There is a related discussion in Section 2.4 of

André Haefliger, *Points multiples d'une application et produit cyclique réduit*,
Amer. J. Math. 83 1961 57–70

where the author refers to an unpublished paper of Steenrod.